# Elements in a subset of bijections of an infinite set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How many elements are there in the subset of bijections of an infinite set $S$ to itself.

I feel like since $S$ is an infinite set then it would be an infinite number of elements? Or would this work:
Suppose $S$ has $n$ elements. If $S$ has $n$ elements, then in order for $S$ to be a 1-1, then there would have to also be $n$ subsets of bijections.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance![image]

Comment: Which subset? $\varnothing$ has none, $\{f\}$ has one, and the entire set - which is also a subset of itself - has infinitely many. Please clarify the question (in the title and the first sentence).

Comment: Thats the exact question in the book, there was no other information given.

Comment: Have you translated the original question to English yourself?

Comment: No the question was originally in english... I copied and pasted it from my online textbook.

Comment: I find that very surprising. Could you take a screenshot or scan the page and post it somewhere online with a link here?

Comment: Not sure how to do that, but perhaps it was a typo in the textbook since my professor did write it. I don't really understand the question because it says "infinite"

Comment: but I think it'd make more sense if it was finite

Comment: It makes no sense at all, since there are many subsets to the set of bijections from $S$ to itself. Some of which are finite, some might not be finite, some might be empty etc.

Comment: So is this problem not possible then?

Comment: If this was a question on math.SE, I'd vote to close it as "Unclear what you're asking" (I haven't here, since you show what you've done; but I'm still not clear as what the question is about).

Comment: I posted a picture of the online text for you to see.

Comment: Yeah, I think that this is an issue of context. And the set of all bijections from $S$ to itself *is* the subset of some larger set. But it's impossible to tell from the screenshot.

Comment: I assume you are considering the set $F$ of all functions from $S$ to itself, and considering the set of bijections of $S$ with itself as a subset of $F$.

Comment: Do you know about infinite cardinalities? Because saying "it is infinite" (when that's the case) is far from enough.

Comment: I am not familiar with infinite cardinalities. I agree with "it is infinite" is not enough, but I don't really understand how to prove it otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

These appear to be Steve Halperin’s *Introduction to Analysis* notes. If so, you have a typo in your version: in [the PDF of the $2014$ version](http://www2.math.umd.edu/~shalper/text.pdf) it reads

> *How many elements are there in the subset of bijections of a finite set $S$ to itself?*

Here *subset* evidently refers to the previous question: that question asked for the number of *all* maps from $S$ to $T$, and now he’s asking how many of them are bijections if $S=T$.